# IllegalArgumentException on hiding System Alert

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to add a system alert on getting a call, just like how TrueCaller app does. It's for an enterprise app, so users are aware about the function.

I can add the system alert but I am not able to hide it. As soon as I hide it, it generates the IllegalArgumentException.

Here's what I am doing to add the system alert -

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        preRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_pre_call_overlay, null);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE| LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE|LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;


        windowManager.addView(preRootView, params);
```

And to hide the view, I call the following code -

```
windowManager.removeView(preRootView);
```

On removing the view this is the error I am getting -

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.LinearLayout{64ea0ff8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-768,473 #7f060007 app:id/preCallBox} not attached to window manager
W/System.err﹕ at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:370)
W/System.err﹕ at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
W/System.err﹕ at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
W/System.err﹕ at com.appcall.CallOverlay.onRefreshData(CallOverlay.java:213)
W/System.err﹕ at com.appcall.Manager.CommandParser.sendRefreshData(CommandParser.java:458)
W/System.err﹕ at com.appcall.Manager.CommandParser.sendExitCode(CommandParser.java:352)
W/System.err﹕ at com.appcall.XMPPService.onCallStateChanged(XMPPService.java:403)
W/System.err﹕ at com.appcall.PhoneStateMonitor.onCallStateChanged(PhoneStateMonitor.java:137)
W/System.err﹕ at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:369)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

I have searched for this exception on SO, but I am only finding the questions about AlertDialogs.

I am not using setContentView for this activity and instead using system alerts. Can it be the cause?

So my question is how can I hide the alert without crashing my app?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was adding preRootView and trying to remove preCallBox. I seriously need to reconsider my naming convention.